# (Using Android Studio) AVD Gets Crash During Launch of My Applicaton

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

I  am New to Android application development. My AVD was working fine a day before but when I try to start it next day it stopped working by throwing the following errors:

```
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
Could not initialize emulated framebufferERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver
```

Please help me to figure out what happend.

Comment: Sharp edge... Finally i found out the solution that i had a complete copy of adt bundle from there i access the AVD manager and ran virtual device from there... when i tried to run my app from android studio it automatically picked up the virtual device... And Still i am using it the same way...

Answer (score 0):

Check out your computer's video drive