# Android Virtual Device is not Launching

Tags: android

Android Emulator is not launching after version upgrade,getting error message like.

```
   "Failed to create Context 0x3005
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
    emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 1536MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
    Could not initialize emulated framebufferCannot set up guest memory 'android_arm': Invalid argument"
```

I edited AVD with low memory devices and I am taking 566 MB of size on disk. Still i cannot resolve the problem.Please help me out of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce your AVD RAM to 512 MB and use Intel_x86.. As i think you are assigning large amount of RAM to your AVD..As your error saying that 1536 MB RAM and you reduced that RAM to 1152MB.. So make sure if you are using Low memory device try to assign specific amount of RAM to your AVD...

Comment: I am taking 5.4"FWVGA device, Resolution->480x854:MDPI. After creating AVD, Showing Resolution 1080x1920:MDPI. Size on Disk is 566 MB. How do i choose less MB RAM in Android Studio?

Comment: In Android Studio go to Tools->Android->AVD Manager After that you will see you devices.. On the right last column click on that edit icon and after that find a button show advance settings after clicking it scroll down the stuff and you will find the RAM area.. So try to change that and it will get fine..

Comment: After editing the RAM size, getting the below error.

Comment: Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: warning: opening audio output failed
Could not initialize emulated framebufferERROR: Could not create renderer: Couldn't find matching render driver

Comment: Try to make another Virtual Device i.e Nexus S.. Try to use built-in Devices if you are a beginner... Go to that AVD manager as i told you above.. there find a button (create virtual device) and then select Nexus S after that you have to select your version.. for now i suggest you to select Jelly Bean API 17 With (armeabi-v7a)... i hope your problem get solved doing this..

Comment: As i commented above if it doesn't work.. then i answered this problem at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853550/using-android-studio-avd-gets-crash-during-launch-of-my-applicaton

Comment: Thank you, I installed android studio on another machine. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

HAXM memory and the amount you put to AVD memory have to be the same. Re install HAXM and choose amount that you selcteced for AVD.

Comment: AVD > Select the device > Edit >RAM -make sure this value is same as the value you gave to HAXM when installing. Did you try uninstalling > installing, could you post the new error message ?

Comment: Directly i re installed HAXM. which is under sdk->extras->intel->Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager->intelhaxm-android.

Comment: Do you use Android Studio? try restarting

Comment: No, manually I re installed it. How to reinstall HAXM using android studio?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. ya, i restated Android Studio and run the application. Got same error.

Comment: seams like you have not selected RAM value properly AVD > Select the device > Edit >RAM =512, Heap size 64 then restart  Android Studio.

Comment: Where do we reduce the RAM size of AVD in Android Studio?